# How to remove the landmark logos on google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating a tourism app for a specific city. I want to remove the landmark logos on provided on google maps because I'm planning to put a different set of pictures on those land marks. I also want to put public transportation routes on it. Is this possible? Or if it is not, is there another approach on doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considerd OSM?
google have some licensing on their maps, OSM is open sourde and should have a commercial license plus there are some good examples for what you want to do

Comment: so if it is an another source for maps, the Google API key is no longer required right?